# How to scale,position an object to the right size in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-deployment, web-frontend, gltf

I just started learning three.js and I wanted to test out importing models using the gltf loader.
when I load a certain 3d model my scene looks like this ,
[image]

but without the model ,the background looks like this (after enabling alpha true and changing the bg of the canvas to a gradient)

[image]

the object im trying to load is this,
[image]

Im assuming it has something to do with the camera angle or object scale ,Below is my complete js code.

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
const gui = new dat.GUI()
loader.load('orange.glb', (gltf) => {
   browserscene.add(gltf.scene)
   gltf.scene.position.x = 10
   gltf.scene.position.y = 20
   gltf.scene.rotation.x = 0.2
   gltf.scene.rotation.z = 0.8
   gltf.scene.scale.x = 3
   gltf.scene.scale.y = 3

 });


  // Debug


  // Canvas
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

  // Scene
  const browserscene = new THREE.Scene()

  // Materials

   const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
   material.color = new THREE.Color(0xFFFE00)

   // Lights

   var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x404040, 0xFFFFFF, 10);
   browserscene.add(light);

   const sizes = {
     width: window.innerWidth,
     height: window.innerHeight
    }

     window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      // Update sizes
      sizes.width = window.innerWidth
      sizes.height = window.innerHeight

       // Update camera
       camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
       camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

       // Update renderer
       renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
       renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
      })


      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
      camera.position.x = 0
      camera.position.y = 0
      camera.position.z = 2
      browserscene.add(camera)


      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
         canvas: canvas, antialias: true, alpha: true
      })
      renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
      renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))

      const animate = () => {

      // Render
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
      renderer.render(browserscene, camera)

    

     }

     animate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the model we probably can't tell you what size or position you should be giving it, but glTF models are intended to be in units of meters. Depending on the source, the model might or might not obey that, e.g. it might have been converted from another format without units, like OBJ.

You can use `THREE.Box3.setFromObject(gltf.scene)` to find the dimensions of the model and adjust, given that your camera is 2m from the origin.